# How to calculate similarity score between English words according to their pronunciation?

Tags: algorithm, similarity

There are many popular algorithms to encode English words to a string according to their pronunciation. e.g., soundex codes are four-character strings composed of a single letter followed by three numbers.

Is there an efficient way to compute a similarity score between 0 and 1?

Comment: Note that soundex _codes_ specifically are intended for names, not random words. Saving the first letter means that you lose any similarity grouping; fixing the length to 4 makes short and long words artificially identical. It's also based on an outdated understanding of language.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility would be to use some edit distance, for instance the [Levinshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), but not on the actual word, but its representation in [soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) or [phonetic representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). The value could be normalized with resprect to the length of the input.

Answer (score 1):

[Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) can only tell you if two words are pronounced the same, but can not calculate the similarity between two words.

[Metaphone3](http://www.amorphics.com/metaphone3.html) (which performs much better than [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)) has a [Result Ranking Algorithm](http://www.amorphics.com/buy_metaphone3.html). Source code available for US$40 (on top of the $240 / $260 you'll pay for Metaphone's source code itself).

Though open source versions of Metaphone3 [may be found online](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/blob/master/main/src/com/google/refine/clustering/binning/Metaphone3.java), the result ranking is only available commercially.

I don't believe that you'll find anything better.

Answer (score 0):

metaphone3 is available packaged with the result ranking algorithm for $260. the free version of metaphone3 in the link is an older version from 2010. the up to date version available commercially is from 2015